# Why do I get LoadError for io/console even after I "gem install io-console"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

If I do this:

> rails generate controller welcome index

I get:

> /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- io/console (LoadError)

But my gem list shows console is installed:

> gem list
>
> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
>
> actionmailer (3.2.17)
>
> actionpack (3.2.17)
>
> activemodel (3.2.17)
>
> activerecord (3.2.17)
>
> activeresource (3.2.17)
>
> activesupport (3.2.17)
>
> arel (3.0.3)
>
> bigdecimal (1.2.5, 1.2.0)
>
> builder (3.0.4)
>
> bundler (1.6.2)
>
> coffee-rails (3.2.2)
>
> coffee-script (2.2.0)
>
> coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
>
> erubis (2.7.0)
>
> execjs (2.0.2)
>
> hike (1.2.3)
>
> i18n (0.6.9)
>
> io-console (0.4.2)
>
> journey (1.0.4)
>
> jquery-rails (3.1.0)
>
> json (1.8.1, 1.7.7)
>
> mail (2.5.4)
>
> mime-types (1.25.1)
>
> multi_json (1.9.2)
>
> polyglot (0.3.4)
>
> psych (2.0.5, 2.0.0)
>
> rack (1.4.5)
>
> rack-cache (1.2)
>
> rack-ssl (1.3.4)
>
> rack-test (0.6.2)
>
> rails (3.2.17)
>
> railties (3.2.17)
>
> rake (10.3.0)
>
> rdoc (4.1.1, 4.0.1, 3.12.2)
>
> sass (3.3.5)
>
> sass-rails (3.2.6)
>
> sprockets (2.2.2)
>
> sqlite3 (1.3.9)
>
> thor (0.19.1)
>
> tilt (1.4.1)
>
> treetop (1.4.15)
>
> tzinfo (0.3.39)
>
> uglifier (2.5.0)
>
> Running as root.

If I do this:

> gem env

I get:

> RubyGems Environment:
>
> RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
>
> RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 451) [x86_64-linux]
>
> INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0
>
> RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby2.0
>
> EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
>
> RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>
> ruby
>
> x86_64-linux
>
> GEM PATHS:
>
> /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0
>
> /root/.gem/ruby/2.0
>
> /usr/share/ruby/gems/2.0
>
> GEM CONFIGURATION:
>
> :update_sources => true
>
> :verbose => true
>
> :backtrace => false
>
> :bulk_threshold => 1000
>
> REMOTE SOURCES:
>
> https://rubygems.org/

If I do this:

> ls -al /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/io-console-0.4.2/

I see the gem installed.

Why do I get a LoadError?

If I do this:

> emacs /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb

and edit this method like so:

```
def require(file)

result = false

print file

print " \n\n "

load_dependency(file) { result = super }

result

end
```

and then I try this again:

> rails generate controller welcome index

then I get this:

> active_support/descendants_tracker
>
> rails/engine/railties
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/delegation
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/to_param
>
> active_support/core_ext/regexp
>
> journey
>
> journey/router
>
> journey/core-ext/hash
>
> journey/router/utils
>
> uri
>
> journey/router/strexp
>
> journey/routes
>
> journey/formatter
>
> journey/parser
>
> racc/parser.rb
>
> racc/cparse
>
> journey/parser_extras
>
> journey/scanner
>
> strscan
>
> journey/nodes/node
>
> journey/visitors
>
> journey/route
>
> journey/path/pattern
>
> journey/gtg/builder
>
> journey/gtg/transition_table
>
> journey/nfa/dot
>
> journey/gtg/simulator
>
> strscan
>
> journey/nfa/builder
>
> journey/nfa/transition_table
>
> journey/nfa/dot
>
> journey/gtg/transition_table
>
> journey/nfa/simulator
>
> strscan
>
> forwardable
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/to_query
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/to_param
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/slice
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/remove_method
>
> action_controller/metal/exceptions
>
> tempfile
>
> stringio
>
> strscan
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access
>
> active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/keys
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/access
>
> active_support/multibyte
>
> active_support/inflector
>
> action_dispatch/http/headers
>
> action_controller/metal/exceptions
>
> rack/utils
>
> fileutils
>
> set
>
> tempfile
>
> rack/multipart
>
> uri/common
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/keys
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/keys
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable
>
> bigdecimal
>
> /home/ec2-user/oscar/config/environments/development.rb
>
> active_support/all
>
> active_support
>
> active_support/time
>
> active_support
>
> date
>
> time
>
> active_support/core_ext/time/publicize_conversion_methods
>
> active_support/core_ext/time/marshal
>
> active_support/core_ext/time/acts_like
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/acts_like
>
> active_support/core_ext/time/calculations
>
> active_support/core_ext/time/conversions
>
> active_support/core_ext/time/zones
>
> active_support/core_ext/date/acts_like
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/acts_like
>
> active_support/core_ext/date/freeze
>
> active_support/core_ext/date/calculations
>
> active_support/core_ext/date/conversions
>
> date
>
> active_support/inflector/methods
>
> active_support/core_ext/date/zones
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/remove_method
>
> active_support/core_ext/date/zones
>
> active_support/core_ext/date_time/acts_like
>
> date
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/acts_like
>
> active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations
>
> active_support/core_ext/date_time/conversions
>
> active_support/core_ext/date_time/zones
>
> active_support/core_ext/time/zones
>
> active_support/core_ext/integer/time
>
> active_support/core_ext/numeric/time
>
> active_support/duration
>
> active_support/core_ext/time/calculations
>
> active_support/core_ext/time/acts_like
>
> active_support/core_ext
>
> active_support/core_ext/array
>
> active_support/core_ext/array/wrap
>
> active_support/core_ext/array/access
>
> active_support/core_ext/array/uniq_by
>
> active_support/core_ext/array/conversions
>
> active_support/core_ext/array/extract_options
>
> active_support/core_ext/array/grouping
>
> enumerator
>
> active_support/core_ext/array/random_access
>
> active_support/core_ext/array/prepend_and_append
>
> active_support/core_ext/benchmark
>
> active_support/core_ext/big_decimal
>
> active_support/core_ext/big_decimal/conversions
>
> active_support/core_ext/class
>
> active_support/core_ext/enumerable
>
> active_support/core_ext/exception
>
> active_support/core_ext/file
>
> active_support/core_ext/file/atomic
>
> active_support/core_ext/file/path
>
> active_support/core_ext/float
>
> active_support/core_ext/float/rounding
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions
>
> active_support/xml_mini
>
> active_support/time
>
> active_support/core_ext/array/wrap
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/reverse_merge
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/inflections
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_dup
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/diff
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/except
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/keys
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/reverse_merge
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/slice
>
> active_support/core_ext/integer
>
> active_support/core_ext/integer/multiple
>
> active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections
>
> active_support/inflector
>
> active_support/core_ext/integer/time
>
> active_support/core_ext/io
>
> active_support/core_ext/kernel
>
> active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting
>
> active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics
>
> active_support/core_ext/kernel/debugger
>
> active_support/core_ext/kernel/singleton_class
>
> active_support/core_ext/load_error
>
> active_support/core_ext/logger
>
> active_support/core_ext/module
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/introspection
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/anonymous
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/reachable
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/attribute_accessors
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/attr_internal
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/delegation
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/synchronization
>
> thread
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing
>
> active_support/core_ext/array/extract_options
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/deprecation
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/deprecation
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/remove_method
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/method_names
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/qualified_const
>
> active_support/core_ext/name_error
>
> active_support/core_ext/numeric
>
> active_support/core_ext/numeric/bytes
>
> active_support/core_ext/numeric/time
>
> active_support/core_ext/object
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/acts_like
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/try
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/conversions
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/to_param
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/to_query
>
> active_support/core_ext/array/conversions
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/instance_variables
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/to_json
>
> json
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/to_param
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/to_query
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/with_options
>
> active_support/option_merger
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge
>
> active_support/core_ext/proc
>
> active_support/core_ext/kernel/singleton_class
>
> active_support/core_ext/process
>
> active_support/core_ext/process/daemon
>
> active_support/core_ext/range
>
> active_support/core_ext/range/blockless_step
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing
>
> active_support/core_ext/range/conversions
>
> active_support/core_ext/range/include_range
>
> active_support/core_ext/range/overlaps
>
> active_support/core_ext/range/cover
>
> active_support/core_ext/regexp
>
> active_support/core_ext/rexml
>
> active_support/core_ext/string
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/conversions
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/filters
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/multibyte
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/multibyte
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/starts_ends_with
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/inflections
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/access
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/xchar
>
> fast_xs
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/behavior
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/interpolation
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/exclude
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/encoding
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/strip
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/try
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/inquiry
>
> active_support/string_inquirer
>
> active_support/core_ext/uri
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> active_support/deprecation
>
> logger
>
> thread
>
> logger
>
> active_support/core_ext/logger
>
> active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors
>
> active_support/deprecation
>
> fileutils
>
> benchmark
>
> zlib
>
> active_support/core_ext/array/extract_options
>
> active_support/core_ext/array/wrap
>
> active_support/core_ext/benchmark
>
> active_support/core_ext/exception
>
> active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors
>
> active_support/core_ext/numeric/bytes
>
> active_support/core_ext/numeric/time
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/to_param
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/inflections
>
> active_support/cache/file_store
>
> active_support/core_ext/file/atomic
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/conversions
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion
>
> rack/utils
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/inflections
>
> sass
>
> sass/version
>
> date
>
> sass/util
>
> erb
>
> set
>
> enumerator
>
> stringio
>
> rbconfig
>
> uri
>
> thread
>
> pathname
>
> sass/root
>
> sass/util/subset_map
>
> set
>
> sass/util/multibyte_string_scanner
>
> strscan
>
> sass/util/normalized_map
>
> delegate
>
> sass/util
>
> sass/util/cross_platform_random
>
> sass/logger
>
> sass/util
>
> sass/engine
>
> set
>
> digest/sha1
>
> sass/cache_stores
>
> stringio
>
> sass/cache_stores/base
>
> sass/cache_stores/filesystem
>
> fileutils
>
> sass/cache_stores/memory
>
> sass/cache_stores/chain
>
> sass/source/position
>
> sass/source/range
>
> sass/source/map
>
> sass/tree/node
>
> sass/tree/root_node
>
> sass/tree/rule_node
>
> pathname
>
> sass/tree/comment_node
>
> sass/tree/node
>
> sass/tree/prop_node
>
> sass/tree/directive_node
>
> sass/tree/media_node
>
> sass/tree/supports_node
>
> sass/tree/css_import_node
>
> sass/tree/variable_node
>
> sass/tree/mixin_def_node
>
> sass/tree/mixin_node
>
> sass/tree/node
>
> sass/tree/trace_node
>
> sass/tree/node
>
> sass/tree/content_node
>
> sass/tree/function_node
>
> sass/tree/return_node
>
> sass/tree/extend_node
>
> sass/tree/node
>
> sass/tree/if_node
>
> sass/tree/node
>
> sass/tree/while_node
>
> sass/tree/node
>
> sass/tree/for_node
>
> sass/tree/node
>
> sass/tree/each_node
>
> sass/tree/node
>
> sass/tree/debug_node
>
> sass/tree/warn_node
>
> sass/tree/import_node
>
> sass/tree/charset_node
>
> sass/tree/at_root_node
>
> sass/tree/visitors/base
>
> sass/tree/visitors/perform
>
> sass/tree/visitors/cssize
>
> sass/tree/visitors/extend
>
> sass/tree/visitors/convert
>
> sass/tree/visitors/to_css
>
> sass/tree/visitors/deep_copy
>
> sass/tree/visitors/set_options
>
> sass/tree/visitors/check_nesting
>
> sass/selector
>
> sass/selector/simple
>
> sass/selector/abstract_sequence
>
> sass/selector/comma_sequence
>
> sass/selector/sequence
>
> sass/selector/simple_sequence
>
> sass/environment
>
> set
>
> sass/script
>
> sass/scss/rx
>
> sass/script/functions
>
> sass/script/value/helpers
>
> sass/script/parser
>
> sass/script/lexer
>
> sass/scss/rx
>
> sass/script/tree
>
> sass/script/tree/node
>
> sass/script/tree/variable
>
> sass/script/tree/funcall
>
> sass/script/functions
>
> sass/util/normalized_map
>
> sass/script/tree/operation
>
> sass/script/tree/unary_operation
>
> sass/script/tree/interpolation
>
> sass/script/tree/string_interpolation
>
> sass/script/tree/literal
>
> sass/script/tree/list_literal
>
> sass/script/tree/map_literal
>
> sass/script/value
>
> sass/script/value/base
>
> sass/script/value/string
>
> sass/script/value/number
>
> sass/script/value/color
>
> sass/script/value/bool
>
> sass/script/value/deprecated_false
>
> sass/script/value/null
>
> sass/script/value/list
>
> sass/script/value/arg_list
>
> sass/script/value/map
>
> sass/scss
>
> sass/scss/rx
>
> sass/scss/script_lexer
>
> sass/scss/script_parser
>
> sass/scss/parser
>
> set
>
> sass/scss/static_parser
>
> sass/script/css_parser
>
> sass/script
>
> sass/script/css_lexer
>
> sass/scss/css_parser
>
> sass/script/css_parser
>
> sass/stack
>
> sass/error
>
> sass/importers
>
> sass/importers/base
>
> sass/importers/filesystem
>
> set
>
> sass/importers/deprecated_path
>
> sass/shared
>
> sass/media
>
> sass/supports
>
> sass/railtie
>
> sass/features
>
> set
>
> sprockets
>
> sprockets/version
>
> sprockets/eco_template
>
> tilt
>
> tilt/string
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/erb
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/etanni
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/haml
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/css
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/csv
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/coffee
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/nokogiri
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/builder
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/markaby
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/liquid
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/radius
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/markdown
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/textile
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/rdoc
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/wiki
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/yajl
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/asciidoc
>
> tilt/template
>
> tilt/plain
>
> tilt/template
>
> sprockets/ejs_template
>
> tilt
>
> sprockets/jst_processor
>
> tilt
>
> sprockets/utils
>
> tilt
>
> tilt
>
> sprockets
>
> action_dispatch/middleware/body_proxy
>
> active_support/whiny_nil
>
> active_support/deprecation
>
> active_support/core_ext/time/zones
>
> tzinfo
>
> tzinfo/ruby_core_support
>
> date
>
> tzinfo/offset_rationals
>
> tzinfo/time_or_datetime
>
> date
>
> time
>
> tzinfo/timezone_definition
>
> tzinfo/timezone_offset_info
>
> tzinfo/timezone_transition_info
>
> date
>
> tzinfo/timezone_index_definition
>
> tzinfo/timezone_info
>
> tzinfo/data_timezone_info
>
> tzinfo/linked_timezone_info
>
> tzinfo/timezone_period
>
> tzinfo/timezone
>
> date
>
> tzinfo/info_timezone
>
> tzinfo/data_timezone
>
> tzinfo/linked_timezone
>
> tzinfo/timezone_proxy
>
> tzinfo/country_index_definition
>
> tzinfo/country_info
>
> tzinfo/country
>
> tzinfo/country_timezone
>
> digest/md5
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/delegation
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors
>
> rack/request
>
> rack/utils
>
> time
>
> action_controller/metal/exceptions
>
> active_support/core_ext/exception
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/keys
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/attribute_accessors
>
> active_record/railties/controller_runtime
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/attr_internal
>
> active_record/log_subscriber
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/attribute_accessors
>
> active_support/core_ext/class/attribute
>
> sprockets
>
> sprockets/base
>
> sprockets/asset_attributes
>
> pathname
>
> sprockets/bundled_asset
>
> sprockets/asset
>
> time
>
> set
>
> sprockets/errors
>
> fileutils
>
> set
>
> zlib
>
> sprockets/caching
>
> sprockets/processed_asset
>
> sprockets/asset
>
> sprockets/utils
>
> sprockets/processing
>
> sprockets/engines
>
> sprockets/mime
>
> rack/mime
>
> sprockets/processor
>
> tilt
>
> sprockets/utils
>
> sprockets/server
>
> time
>
> uri
>
> sprockets/static_asset
>
> sprockets/asset
>
> fileutils
>
> zlib
>
> sprockets/trail
>
> sprockets/errors
>
> pathname
>
> pathname
>
> sprockets/charset_normalizer
>
> tilt
>
> sprockets/context
>
> base64
>
> rack/utils
>
> sprockets/errors
>
> sprockets/utils
>
> pathname
>
> set
>
> sprockets/directive_processor
>
> pathname
>
> shellwords
>
> tilt
>
> yaml
>
> sprockets/index
>
> sprockets/base
>
> sprockets/safety_colons
>
> tilt
>
> hike
>
> logger
>
> pathname
>
> tilt
>
> pathname
>
> hike/extensions
>
> hike/normalized_array
>
> hike/index
>
> pathname
>
> hike/paths
>
> pathname
>
> hike/normalized_array
>
> digest/md5
>
> active_support/cache/file_store
>
> action_controller/railtie
>
> active_support/inflector/methods
>
> active_support/dependencies
>
> rack/utils
>
> thread
>
> rack/body_proxy
>
> securerandom
>
> active_support/core_ext/string/access
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> active_support/core_ext/time/conversions
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> action_dispatch/http/request
>
> action_dispatch/middleware/exception_wrapper
>
> active_support/deprecation
>
> action_dispatch/http/request
>
> action_dispatch/middleware/exception_wrapper
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/delegation
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/keys
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store
>
> rack/utils
>
> rack/request
>
> rack/session/abstract/id
>
> time
>
> rack/request
>
> rack/response
>
> securerandom
>
> action_dispatch/middleware/cookies
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> rack/session/cookie
>
> openssl
>
> rack/request
>
> rack/response
>
> rack/session/abstract/id
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions
>
> action_dispatch/http/request
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access
>
> set
>
> active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> action_dispatch/http/mime_types
>
> rack/utils
>
> digest/md5
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> thread
>
> monitor
>
> set
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/deprecation
>
> time
>
> rack/utils
>
> rack/mime
>
> yaml
>
> i18n/core_ext/hash
>
> i18n/core_ext/kernel/surpress_warnings
>
> active_support/core_ext/hash/except
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion
>
> active_support/core_ext/enumerable
>
> active_support/inflector
>
> action_dispatch/routing/redirection
>
> action_dispatch/http/request
>
> active_support/core_ext/uri
>
> rack/utils
>
> rails/generators
>
> rails/generators
>
> rails/generators
>
> rails/commands/generate
>
> rails/generators
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion
>
> rails/generators/controller/controller/controller_generator
>
> generators/controller/controller/controller_generator
>
> rails/generators/controller/controller_generator
>
> generators/controller/controller_generator
>
> rails/generators/rails/controller/controller_generator
>
> active_support/core_ext/module/introspection
>
> rails/generators/base
>
> rails/generators/generated_attribute
>
> active_support/time
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion
>
> active_support/core_ext/object/blank
>
> thor/shell/basic
>
> tempfile
>
> io/console

and then I get the error:

> /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `require': cannot load such file -- io/console (LoadError)

I notice that most gems have a file named after the gem. For instance, polygon has "polygon.rb":

> ls -al
>   /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.4/lib/polyglot.rb
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2121 Apr 17 15:13 /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.4/lib/polyglot.rb

and sass has "sass.rb":

> [root@ip-172-31-38-140 oscar]# ls -al
>   /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/sass-3.3.5/lib/sass.rb
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4188 Apr 17 15:23 /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/sass-3.3.5/lib/sass.rb

But not io-console:

> [root@ip-172-31-38-140 oscar]# ls -al
>   /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/io-console-0.4.2/lib/
>
> drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 17 15:44 .
>
> drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 17 15:44 ..
>
> drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 17 15:44 console
>
> [root@ip-172-31-38-140 oscar]# ls -al /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/io-console-0.4.2/lib/console/
>
> drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 17 15:44 .
>
> drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 17 15:44 ..
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  331 Apr 17 15:44 size.rb

I see this file:

> /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/io-console-0.4.2/console.so

so I tried:

> ln -s /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/io-console-0.4.2/console.so /usr/share/ruby/gems/2.0/console

but that did nothing. I still get the same error.

Full stack trace:

rails generate controller welcome index

/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- io/console (LoadError)

```
from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell/basic.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell/color.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell.rb:17:in `shell'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/generators.rb:171:in `invoke'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'

from script/rails:6:in `require'

from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I fixed this by adding this to my Gemfile:
gem 'io-console'
then I ran bundle install and then everything worked. 
This is why I prefer to program in Clojure -- I do not have to deal with these weird dependency issues.

Comment: Adding this to the answer as it solved my problem as well. Thanks @cerhovice

Answer (score 5):

I had to add following line in `Gemfile`:

```
  gem 'io-console'
```

then I ran

```
bundle install
```

And it worked well !